# Java Script Only one function call works

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple registration form. As soon as the user types his phone number and leaves the textbox (onblur), a few of the other fields get auto populated, using an Ajax call to a php script, and this piece works fine. Now, I'm trying to add another onblur() event ON A DIFFERENT TEXT FIELD that has nothing to do with the ajax call or the fields populated but is in the same form. However, when I create this function in java script, the event does not get fired. More over, the original ajax call also stops working i.e., the onblur event for the phone number field also does not get fired (I've confirmed this by putting a few alert messages in place). I'm stuck and given that I'm a novice web developer, it has been an irritable ride. So any help or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

My java script code is in the same file as my HTML code, i.e., between the  tags. When I create both the functions between the same script tags, none work, but when I put them in separate script tags, the first function (ajax call behind Phone number) gets fired on blur but the second one does not. The functions in point are: vldtnPhNo() and enabtnRegCmplt().

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function vldtnPhNo()
      {
        var xhr;
        var dvPhNo = document.getElementById("divPhNo");

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();             

            var FoneNumb = document.getElementById("txtPhNo").value;

            xhr.open("POST", "verify.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");

            xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {

                    document.getElementById("txtRegInv").value = xhr.responseText;

                    var rstOftheTxt = xhr.responseText;


                        document.getElementById("txtPhNo").value=rstOftheTxt;
                        document.getElementById("txtPhPop").value=rstOftheTxt;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("txtPhNo").value='waiting';
                        document.getElementById("txtPhPop").value='waiting';
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.send("txtPhNo=" + FoneNumb);


        }

        else 
        {
            throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
        }
      }


      function enabtnRegCmplt(){

       If(txtRegInv.value!="")
       {
        var UsrNm;
        var Psswd;
        var RePsw;
        var PostBackInfo;

        UsrNm = document.getElementById('txtUsrNm');
        Psswd = document.getElementById('txtPsw');
        RePsw = document.getElementById('txtrePsw');
        txtRegInv = document.getElementById('txtRegInv');

        If (RePsw.value!="" && Psswd.value!="" && UsrNm.value!="" && RePsw.value==Psswd.value)
        {
           document.getElementById('btnRegCmplt').disabled="False";
        }
        else if(UsrNm.value=="")
        {
            UsrNm.value="Please Enter UserName";
        }
        else if(Psswd.value=="")
        {
            Psswd.value="Please Enter Password";
        }
        else if(RePsw.value=="")
        {
            RePsw.value="Does not match";
        }
       }
      }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very messy. One of the reason why it's necessary to write neat code. Your brackets are wrong, thus the whole code isn't executed (`else` statement is connected with `function`).

The `If` statement doesn't exist, try `if` instead (lowercase **I**).

**Other things:**

use `onkeyup` instead.

**2:** 
For the vars you could do:

```
var UsrNm,
    Psswd,
    RePsw,
    PostBackInfo
;
```

**OR**

```
var UsrNm = document.getElementById('txtUsrNm'),
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Kai and Rahul....changing the I to lower case did it...thanks peeps.....appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax mistake

An extra brace }

```
        `else
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtPhNo").value='waiting';
                    document.getElementById("txtPhPop").value='waiting';
                }
            }
        }`
```

Remove one brace after the else condition